# .htaccess url rewrite rule to subdirectory not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want this: `RewriteRule ^paper$ /express/index.php?c=p [L]` but it does not work. Instead, it's trying to send me to `/index.php?c=p`, ignoring the subdirectory `express` altogether.  However, `RewriteRule ^express/paper$ /express/index.php?c=p [L]` works.  This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^paper$ /express/index.php?c=p [L]
RewriteRule ^express/paper$ /express/index.php?c=p [L]
```

The url I WANT is just http://site.com/paper but I have to do http://site.com/express/paper to get the rewrite rule to work.

And yes, I only use one of those rewrite rules at a time.

**UPDATE**

Well, I'm not really getting any responses, so I'm going to go ahead and close this browser tab.  I'll check back now and then but don't be offended if it takes a little while.  Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file stored? At root level or in a directory? Could it be a cache problem?

Comment: @Kay It's at root level.  I don't think it's a cache issue because if I change the RewriteRule to anything else (`^pencils$`), the new word works, but only with `express/` in front of it.  Plus it breaks if I take the `express/` out from in front of it, so its definitely seeing the change.